# How to skip an iteration of a loop after some time in Python?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, timeout

I have a code with a loop that I need to skip an iteration if it is taking too much time.

Example:

```
list = ['a', 'b', 'c', ......]

for x in list:

    #do something that takes time
```

In my code, the list has several paths.
I loop through every path of that list to do some actions in files, but there are some files that take too long. I don't want the script to be stuck in a path for more than half an hour... If it takes more than 30 minutes while executing it, I want it to skip that path and go to the next on the list.

Comment: Please elaborate your requirement. The `list` has something when processed, takes more time?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Timeout on a function call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492519/timeout-on-a-function-call)

Comment: @Rohit Babu, it's just a list with Paths. I loop through every path of that list to do some actions in files, but there are some files that take too long. I don't want the scrip to be stuck in a path for more than half an hour... If it takes more than 30 minutes, I want it to skip that path and go to the next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean that you want to break out of the loop if a certain amount of time has elapsed. If so, take a look at the *time* module. You can use features from there to note the time before you enter the loop then, at appropriate points in the code, compare the elapsed time from your initial record of the start time and continue accordingly

Answer (score 1):

I've came up with this solution:

```
import time
start_time = time.time()

#a lot of code in the middle

print(start_time)

list=['1', '2', '3', '4']


for i in list:
    
    start_time = time.time()


    while True:

        print("hello world {}".format(i))

        current_time = time.time()
        elapsed_time = current_time - start_time

        print(elapsed_time)    

        if elapsed_time > 3: #test for 3seconds
            print("More than {} seconds".format(elapsed_time))
            del elapsed_time
            break
   
print("exited the loop")
```

Answer (score -1):

You might like this code

```
import pprint as p
llist = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
HashMap = {}
for i, x in enumerate(llist):
    HashMap[x] = i
    # Your condition
    if len(HashMap) > 20:
        break  # You can do continue 

p.pprint(HashMap, width = 200, sort_dicts = False)
```

**Explanation**

Imported `pprint` to print beautifully

changed the var name from `list` to `llist` because I don't want to mask *built-ins*

Created a dictionary `HashMap` to store the index of the items and the items

looped on `llist` using `enumerate()` to get those indices

After loop first step was to append the item to `HashMap` so that we keep the *count*

Then the condition will come.....

Then checking length of `HashMap`, if it exceed the *condition* then break

Finally to print it

Comment: This has nothing to do with time taken by the loop.

Comment: "there is nothing much to explain"—and yet an explanation would help. Please read [answer].

Comment: @Chris this tell why -1

Comment: @AadeshGurav, I don't know. Only the person who cast that vote knows why they did it. But a few guesses: See matszwecja's and my comments above. Or possibly the fact that you posted an [image of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577).

Comment: @matszwecja, I gave the answer from what I understood

Comment: @AadeshGurav from the question: "I have a code with a loop that I need to skip an iteration if it is taking too much time." Your answer skips the whole loop, not a single iteration and it does this based on number of iterations, not on time.

Comment: @matszwecja Okay, understood!